# I've created a python script to import excel sheets into my DB, But now i want create Gui which will take file path as input

Tags: python, pandas

So i want add GUI in to my script as i already created .exe file of my script and it will take simple file-path from user and and write it into my database.
My code of taking input:

```
filename = input("Input the Filename: ")
dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, usecols=['SR_NO','NTN'], sheet_name=None)
```

Is there any way that when i run script a gui can pop up and take file path as input and pass it to my script

Answer (score 0):

If you only need something simple, you can use Tkinter (it's already built-in in Python) and its `askopenfile` function.
More information about the usage can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile

And here are a few examples on how to use this:
https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-open-file-dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Tkinter**, **PyQt** and **Kivy** to build a GUI app. Although Tkinter is simple, it is not as beautiful as PyQt.

Note that: PyQt and PySide are very similar. you can learn more from [here](https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/pyqt5-vs-pyside2/).

> [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro/) - PyQt is a set of Python bindings for The Qt Company's Qt application framework and runs on all platforms supported by Qt including Windows, macOS, Linux, iOS and Android.

> [Kivy](https://kivy.org/) - Open source Python library for rapid development of applications
> that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps.

> [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) - The tkinter package (“Tk interface”) is the standard Python interface to the Tcl/Tk GUI toolkit. Both Tk and tkinter are available on most Unix platforms, including macOS, as well as on Windows systems